# MongoDb_ find multiple value in one field

Tags: php, mongodb, find

`{ "_id": "apples", "qty": 5, "packing": "cardboard" }, { "_id": "bananas", "qty": 7 }, { "_id": "oranges", "qty": { "in stock": 8, "ordered": 12 }, }, { "_id": "avocados", "qty": "fourteen" }`

How to find apples and oranges only in one find query.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `find({"_id":"apples","_id":"oranges"})`
Code is wrong and only shows oranges and not both

Answer (score 0):

Use the [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```
db.collection.find({ _id: { $in: [ "apples", "oranges" ] } })
```

Comment: @PranjitBorah In this case, please accept the answer.